# Muliple Order by MYSql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have stores records in my table and I want to sort them on the basis of highest rating of store and which has  nearest distance to my location.

```
    SELECT rating,
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) 
                   * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
                   * cos( radians( lon ) 
                       - radians(-122) ) 
                   + sin( radians(37) ) 
                   * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
                 )
   ) AS distance 

FROM mystores sr



order by sr.rating desc ,distance asc
```

It is not giving me my desired results

Table Mystores

```
id|rating|distance
66  5        55
55  4        56
99  3        60
```

Comment: Include some sample data and show how you want to sort them.

Comment: I just want to fetch that stores which has highest rating and least distance

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want just the closest store and you want to ignore all other with the same rank but with bigger distance. 
The group by raiting allows us to get the minimal distance for each raiting.

```
 select m1.* 
 from mystores  m1
 join (
      select m.raiting, 
        min(m.distance) distance 
      from mystores m
      group by m.raiting  
     ) m2
  on m2.raiting = m1.raiting   and
     m2.distance = m1.distance
  order by m1.raiting desc, m1.distance asc
```